# PowerShell Snapin Cmdlet CommandNotFoundException

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet, snap-in, pssnapin

Currently I'm trying to create my first PowerShell Snapin. I followed this tutorial: [How to create a PowerShell Snapin](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-how-to-create-a-powershell-snapin-part-1) and everything works fine until I'm trying to invoke my custom cmdlet. In addition I added a "Post Build Event" to register the assembly.

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.exe" $(TargetPath)
```

Afterwards I added the Snapin and it worked like a charm:

```
Add-PSSnapin CustomSrv.Commands
```

Path to the assembly for the System.Automation reference:

```
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\System.Management.Automation.dll
```

As my Target Platform I selected x86 and I'm also executing everything in x86 PowerShell. Platform is set to "Active (Any CPU)"

This is my cmdlet code:

```
namespace CustomSrv.Commands
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommunications.Connect, "CustomSrv")]
    public class TestCmdlet1 : Cmdlet
    {
        protected override void BeginProcessing()
        {
            WriteObject("BeginProcessing() method - Execution has begun");
        }
        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            WriteObject("ProcessRecord() method - Executing the main code");
        }
        protected override void EndProcessing()
        {
            WriteObject("EndProcessing() method - Finalizing the execution");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting when I'm trying to invoke the Cmdlet:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Connect-CustomSrv
Connect-CustomSrv: The term 'Connect-CustomSrv' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-CustomSrv
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Connect-CustomSrv:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What I'm a doing wrong, is there something setup wrong concerning the targeting platform (x86)?

Comment: You should be aware that snap-ins are deprecated (and have been since v2); you should be building modules instead. And yes, you [can create binary modules](http://csharpening.net/?p=738)

Comment: What is the powershell version you are using? Do a $PSVersionTable to make sure. And what is the .Net version you are using for your assembly? And like alroc says. Snapins are deprecated, look up modules. You can have pure PowerShell modules so you don't even need Visual Studio or care about targets and what not.

Comment: As I'm intending to use the Snapin with Pash, which only supports Snapins, sadly switching to Modules is not an option for me...

I'm using .NET Version 3.5 and PowerShell Version 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose x86 as your platform you also need to make sure you are using the x86 version of PowerShell. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847733.aspx) on how to do that. You probably are using the x64 version of powershell, which is the default. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558577/c-sharp-powershell-snapin-not-registering-using-installutil) some more information.

Or change the target to AnyCPU and register the snapin with installutil twice. Once with the 32 bits version and also with the 64 bits version (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\installutil.exe).

Answer (score 0):

If you are making in some IDE like `atom` 
You should open atom from PowerShell, like

**just type** `atom` there

Should work

Answer (score 0):

If you are making in some IDE like `atom` 
You should open atom from PowerShell, like

**just type** `atom` there

Should work

Answer (score -2):

This fixed it for me: https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/powershell/105/powershel-security-error.html

Run your PowerShell as admin and write:

```
 PS C:\> Get-ExecutionPolicy -list  

 Scope     ExecutionPolicy
            -----     ---------------
    MachinePolicy     Undefined
       UserPolicy     Undefined
          Process     Undefined
      CurrentUser     Undefined
     LocalMachine     RemoteSigned
```

then:

```
PS C:\> Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
```

Hope it works!